# Aligning text with an fluid width div with images

Tags: html, css

I have a div, whose header text is aligned to the right.  Next is an unordered list whose list items are images that I have floating left.

As you expand the browser horizontally, the images align horizontally (more per row) as more space becomes available.

The text, however, stays aligned to the right and in the moment where a new image cannot align horizontally, there is a mis-alignment between the text and the farthest right image.

I would like to align the text to the image farthest right, rather than to the parent div.  Is that possible?

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/jcDqW/

```
<div class="container">
    <span>Text goes here.</span>
    <ol>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTsOZfG8edaAiTfWbHx1a26hJIhUbZPbLzCH2BHakudlSTtI5SZOSEyvFGJpw" /></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: auto;
}

.container span {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
}

.container li img  {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), [Tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/) or [CSSDesk](http://cssdesk.com/) sample of your code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jcDqW/  Notice when you expand the browser, the text stays aligned to the right even when an image is still "stuck" on the next row "waiting" for more horizontal space.  I want the text to only go as far as the farthest image on the first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/psc4D/) — resize your browser window and marvel in the magic:

[image: jsFiddle Screenshot]

[image: jsFiddle Screenshot]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <span>Text goes here.</span>

    <ol>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /></li>
    </ol>

    <br class="clear" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript** (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        box = $('.container');

        var width = box.width();
        var itemCount = box.find('li').length;
        var itemWidth = box.find('li').width();
        var margin = width - (itemCount * itemWidth);

        if (margin <= 0) {
            margin = width % itemWidth;
        }

        $('.container > span').css({
            'margin-right': margin
        });
    });
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 10px;
    width: auto;
}

.container span {
    background: pink;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: auto;
}

.container li {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
}

.container li img {
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

*Note: This technique isn't bulletproof, but provides a simplistic example of the effect you desire.*

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you.  Can you think of any situations that I should investigate before putting this on a live site?  Just curious since you mention it's not bulletproof.

Comment: If you keep the HTML/CSS simple — or don't modify it at all — you won't have any issues. The logic for changing the margin on window resize isn't robust enough to handle varying widths, margins and padding on the `<li>` and `<img />` elements, but the example I posted works just fine on all major browsers.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll go ahead and give it a through testing before I go live.  I appreciate your help and I hope you have a great remainder of the week!

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you can accomplish with CSS alone. There is probably a way to do it with JavaScript, if that is something you're interested in doing.

Comment: Crud.  I'm definitely interested in a javascript solution though.  Would it basically have to be an algorithm that checks the browser width vs. combined image size in the container area, then spaces the span accordingly?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. You'd bind it to the resize event of the browser window, then you'd have to calculate the parent element's width, and the width of its child elements (plus margins) to work out the actual size of the child elements on the first row. It's far from impossible, but wouldn't be the smoothest effect.